# CRUD é um padrão de arquitetura?

Tags: design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, crud

CRUD é um padrão de arquitetura de projeto, que se pode explicar em diferentes visões?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Isso envolve história.

O termo é usado muito relacionado à banco de dados, mas também para telas que se comportam dentro das operações básicas que um banco de dados costuma realizar.

O termo original era Matriz de CRUD. Ele se referia às operações de Criação (**C**reate), leitura (**R**ead), atualização (**U**pdate) e remoção (**D**elete) de um dado no banco de dados. E a possibilidade de criar uma interface de tela que simbolize isso para o usuário, em geral chamado de CRUD Screen.

Com o tempo as pessoas abreviaram só usando CRUD e aí não se sabe com exatidão do que está falando.

De qualquer forma é uma nomenclatura para algo que acontece. Não é uma arquitetura, não é um padrão de projeto tradicional, ainda que se assemelha em certos contextos porque indica algo que uma aplicação faz, mas não com o detalhes para ser um *design pattern*, tão pouco é um idioma.

Ele não deixa de ser um padrão de fazer certas coisas, mas não um DP, não definido como deve ser.

Há quem use o termo CRUD Layer, então de uma certa forma ele pode ser considerado uma camada, mas isso é esquisito quando se considera outras formas de ver a aplicação. O CRUD pode ocorrer em várias camadas da aplicação. Em um MVC o CRUD tem uma *view*, um *controller* e um *model*. O importante é ele fazer essas 4 operações de acesso/manipulação de dados (nem precisa ser exatamente um banco de dados tradicional, nem precisa ser um SGDB relacional, embora seja bem comum).

É quase algo informal como usamos o termo hoje, para indicar que está cuidando de um cadastro básico. Curiosamente em aplicações reais bem pensadas a remoção não costuma ser uma operação necessária e correta. As pessoas fazem sem pensar porque elas costumam só seguir receitas de bolo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 10):

Não, **CRUD** (acrônimo do inglês **Create**, **Read**, **Update** and **Delete**) são as quatro operações básicas (criação, consulta, atualização e destruição de dados) utilizadas em bases de dados relacionais (RDBMS) fornecidas aos utilizadores do sistema.

Answer (score 1):

CRUD é um acrônimo para referências operações comuns de usuários nos dados (conjunto de dados por "domínio"). Por exemplo, realizar as operações de criar, recuperar, atualizar ou excluir registros de Produtos em um sistema.

- C - **C**reate - Criar
- R - **R**ead - Ler
- U - **U**pdate - Atualizar
- D - **D**elete - Excluir

Este post: [O que é CRUD](https://mazer.dev/pt-br/blog/artigos/crud/), trás informações aprofundadas e exemplos com SQL e algumas linguagens sobre o conceito de CRUD.